# Theme syntax color for custom language in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was able to successfully add basic language support for ColdFusion in visual studio code and for the most part it seems to work properly.

The only issue is that the syntax highlighting does not work at all, specifically the colorization. Otherwise the file extension association works and bracket highlight works and even the commenting rules work.

I used the yo code generator to create the new language.

I got the .tmLanguage file from here:
https://github.com/textmate/coldfusion.tmbundle

I feel like there must be a step I'm missing in order to get the new language to work with the theme being used.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: added package.json

```js
{
    "name": "cf",
    "displayName": "ColdFusion",
    "description": "ColdFusion VSCode Support",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "epetti",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^0.10.1"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Languages"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "coldfusion",
            "aliases": ["ColdFusion", "coldfusion"],
            "extensions": [".cfm",".cfml",".cfc"],
            "configuration": "./coldfusion.configuration.json"
        }],
        "grammars": [{
            "language": "coldfusion",
            "scopeName": "text.html.cfm",
            "path": "./syntaxes/coldfusion.tmLanguage"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: I added the package.json to the post.

Comment: I recently did this successfully and your package.json looks good to me. Are the files you are editing specifically cfm files, or by chance are they cfc or cfml files. If its the latter you may need to update your scope setting.